# iPhone app identifier?

Tags: iphone, app-store

What is the unique identifier for an iPhone app?

In the info.plist file, there are keys:

- Bundle display name
- Executable file
- Bundle identifier
- Bundle name

If I have already submitted an app on the AppStore before. Then I change some of the keys in the project. Which of the above can be changed freely and AppStore still considers my app is same as the existing one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple identifies your app with the bundle identifier (com.yourcompany.yourappname). You are free to change the others.